# Baking Rewards Analysis

Tags: baker

As we know the bakers for the specific cycle receive the rewards after some cycles and not in that current cycle . Below are the transactions for one particular baker which i am not able to analyse

"balance_updates": [

```
        {
            "kind": "contract",
            "contract": "tz1TzaNn7wSQSP5gYPXCnNzBCpyMiidCq1PX",
            "change": "-512000000"
        },
        {
            "kind": "freezer",
            "category": "deposits",
            "delegate": "tz1TzaNn7wSQSP5gYPXCnNzBCpyMiidCq1PX",
            "cycle": 124,
            "change": "512000000"
        },
        {
            "kind": "freezer",
            "category": "rewards",
            "delegate": "tz1TzaNn7wSQSP5gYPXCnNzBCpyMiidCq1PX",
            "cycle": 124,
            "change": "16000000"
        },


         {
            "kind": "freezer",
            "category": "deposits",
            "delegate": "tz2TSvNTh2epDMhZHrw73nV9piBX7kLZ9K9m",
            "cycle": 119,
            "change": "-106304000000"
        },
        {
            "kind": "freezer",
            "category": "fees",
            "delegate": "tz2TSvNTh2epDMhZHrw73nV9piBX7kLZ9K9m",
            "cycle": 119,
            "change": "-181552"
        },
        {
            "kind": "freezer",
            "category": "rewards",
            "delegate": "tz2TSvNTh2epDMhZHrw73nV9piBX7kLZ9K9m",
            "cycle": 119,
            "change": "-3266333328"
        },
```

- There are 2 types of type:freezer where in one type of freezer rewards and deposit are positive and in one we have negative.
- And if this is where Baker receives the rewards how much reward did the baker receive . can any one help me understand the calculation

Answer (score 1):

All amounts are expressed in mutez (1e6). The baker, tz1TzaNn7, appears to have baked only 1 block. This requires a bond of 512XTZ. Their reward is 16XTZ. Rewards are equal to standard endorsement (2xtz) and block (16xtz) rewards plus any fees included in any blocks they bake. When rewards are unfrozen, previously locked bond is also unfrozen so you will see different kinds of credits to the same account.

Comment: Thanks for quick help . I completely understand baker, tz1TzaNn7, appears to have baked only 1 block so  bond(deposit) is of 512XTZ thats where there is a -512XTZ from baker account and gets a reward of 16XTZ but how there is no fee involved in this ? Again for baker tz2TSvNTh fees ,rewards and deposits all are in negative how do we logically understand this like atleast rewards should be positive

Comment: Fees come from operations/transactions/reveal/etc. if a block has no operations, there are no fees to give to baker.